# How to deploy a Rails application through Core FTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my Rails application to a hosting site through Core FTP. I set up all the required settings in Core FTP. So, I transferred the files through [Core FTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZCAt.jpg).

But, when I went to my webpage, it just showed the list of all the files.

[My webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYJa1.jpg)

So, my question is, how can I deploy those files properly, so that it shows the webpage instead of the list of website files?

Comment: Shirt answer, you can't. ftp stands for `File Transfer Protocol` and that's the only thing it does... Transfer files

Comment: So, what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: You either need shell access or a hosting provider with deploying tools. Plus your hosting needs to support rails. This is not PHP. Heroku, for instance, is a hosting solution that provides environment for rails projects. You need to research.